Windows nginx as proxy passing to https://localhost - Certificate issues
we are having the following setup and i am struggling with certificates and how all works together.
I am running a web application on a windows machine that is served (only) over https://localhost:8080 (mention the https here)
On the same machine i am using nginx as a reverse proxy to serve this application to domainname.com
The nginx is configured with a valid external ssl certificate like:
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name domainname.com;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          https://localhost:8080;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

    }
    
    ...
}

But i am getting the error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
How to deal with this? Do i need to include the self signed https-certificate on localhost to the nginx certificate as a intermediate?
Any suggestions are welcome!

I fixed it myself, the problem was that a part of the fullchain was missing.

Did you try to disable upstream server certificate check with   proxy_ssl_verify off;? Though it should be off by default,
    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          https://localhost:8080;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
      proxy_ssl_verify off;

    }


Reference

But your upstream server hosting https://localhost:8080 must be configured with a server certificate, valid or not, to ensure SSL/TLS handshake can happen properly. You can run openssl s_client -connect localhost:8080 to validate if it has been configured already.
